# Ошибка CORS при обращению к локальному серверу

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

Тренируюсь в написание запросов на чистом js через разные компоненты, сейчас делаю через Ajax(пробовал и через web socket) и решил еще написать свой мини сервер на питоне и при обращении получаю ошибку в консоли браузера:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost: 9090' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.
```

Честно говоря не понимаю как это исправить и всю суть данной ошибки темболее если это локальный сервер и все это расположено на одном компе вот код js:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>requestJs</title>
</head>
<body>
<button class="myButton">SEND</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
let theButton = document.querySelector(".myButton");
    theButton.addEventListener('click',function() {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onload = function() {
 alert(`Статус: ${xhr.status}; Результат: ${xhr.response}`)
};

xhr.onerror = function() {
  alert('Ошибка запроса');
};

xhr.open("GET", "localhost:9090", true);
xhr.send();
    })

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

И вот код сервера python:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('localhost', 9090))
sock.listen(5)
conn, addr = sock.accept()

print ('connected:', addr)

while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    conn.send(data.upper())

conn.close()
```

Помогите пожалуйста, как исправить, что не так?

Comment: а кто тебе сказал , что  у тебя в браузере идет обращение по websocket? https://learn.javascript.ru/websocket
у тебя https://learn.javascript.ru/search?query=XMLHttpRequest

Comment: @Вадим Да перепутал просто, уже исправил, но это сути не меняет ошибка и при web-socket возникает

Comment: откуда у тебя запускается страница браузера? с сервера python?
походу страницу ты открываешь просто как html файл, вот отсюда и ошибка

Comment: @Вадим Да я открываю страницу просто как Html но это же сути менять не должно не так ли? На странице просто работает Js файл который обращается к независмо работающей программе - python сервер. Я честно не понимаю откуда ошибка, объясните пожалуйста

Comment: @Ihar Я это уже читал) Я понимаю суть ошибки но не знаю как ее исправить. Я увидел что написано что надо вставить надпись Access-Control-Allow-Origin в какой то заголовок ответа на сервера но я честно говоря не понимаю куда конкретно я должен вставлять эту надпись на своем сервере питон, где этот заголовок? Если поможете буду очень признателен

Comment: @Ihar к слову, я понял что браузеры это блокируют но а как это обойти? Какие в моем случае есть варианты?

Comment: @Ihar понял хорошо спасибо!)

Comment: @leocoolguy 0 надо просто сделать простейший сервер

Comment: @Вадим ну так я вроде это как и сделал) только на сокетах. И пишет эту ошибку

Comment: @leocoolguy 0 ты не это сделал, сервер - это когда ты с него открываешь загружаешь) страницу. Поэтому надо начать с создания сервера. ну вот к примеру https://iximiuz.com/ru/posts/writing-python-web-server-part-3/

Comment: @Вадим Все я походу понял спасибо большое